# Selenium find all the elements which have two divs

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to collect texts and images from a website to help collect missing people related tweets. Here is the problem:

Some tweets don't have images so the corresponding `<div class='c' ....>` has only one `<div>...</div>`.
Some tweets have images, so the corresponding `<div class='c' ....>` has two `<div>...</div>`, as shown in the following codes:

```
<div class='c' id="M_D*****">
  <div>...</div>
```

and

```
<div class='c' id="M_D*****">
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
```

I intend to check whether a tweet has an image, i.e. find out whether the corresponding `<div class='c' ....>` has two  `<div>...</div>`.

PS: The following codes are used to collect all the texts and image URLs but not all tweets have images so I want to match them by solving the above problem.

```
tweets = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ctt']")
graph_links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[@alt='img' and @class='ib']")
```

This is a public welfare program, which aims to help the missing people go back home.

Comment: If it's a public site, can you share the page with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By collecting the text and the images separately, I think that it's going to be impossible to match the text with the related image after the fact. I would suggest a different approach. I would search for the `<div class='c'...>` that contains both the text and the optional image. Once you have the "container" DIV, you can then get the text and see if an image exists and put them all together. Without all the relevant HTML, you may have to tweak the code below but it should give you an idea on how to approach this.

```
containers = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.c")
for container in containers:
    print container.find_element_by_css_selector("span.ctt").text // the tweet text
    images = container.find_elements_by_css_selector("img.ib")
    if len(images) > 0 // see if the image exists
        print images[0].get_attribute("src") // the URL of the image
    print "-------------" // separator between tweets
```

Answer (score 0):

The html you provided is probably not enough, but basing on it I suggest xpath: `//div[@id='M_D*****' and ./div//img]` which find div with specified id and containing div with image.

But answering directly to your question:

`//div[./div[2] and not(./div[3])]` will find all divs with exactly 2 div children